# Re-align HST narrowband images to GOODS-S

Tags: hubble-telescope, alignment

I want to re-align the image data of filter F658N to GOODS-South catalog with TweakReg. I used the external catalog of image data generated by SExtractor as input catalog (threshold is set to 5.0) because of the artifacts. Although I can find some matches by visual check using ds9，the TweakReg can't detect the matches between the input catalog and the reference catalog to align my images to the GOODS-S catalog.

I have tried different searchrad and threshold, but it just didn't work.
This problem confused me some days, I really need help. Thank you in advance!